# What is the recommended scripting language for talking between Flash and facebook API?

Tags: flash, facebook

Currently I have a flash based application (game) which I need to put on facebook, the users could save their scores and resume their game. For the task I was wondering which scripting language would be appropriate. And are there any API's available which could help me in the process. Or does one has to make all of it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out:

[Facebook flash api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/)

[Fb:swf tab](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:swf) to render a flash object within your facebook app

And the all-important bridge to communicate both (you must use it because Facebook sets the Flash attribute **AllowScriptAccess** to *never* for security reasons) :

[Fb:fbjs-bridge](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:fbjs_bridge)

Comment: Thanks for the help, that clears out the flash part. Now what if I want to save the pictures/scores of users in a database. What would you recommend how do I communicate between flash and the database and save the information retrieved from facebook.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, as long as it has a client library for the Facebook API (PHP, Ruby on Rails, Python do) and you're comfortable with it. Go to: http://developers.facebook.com/get_started.php for tips on how to get started. From there you can download the PHP client libraries (which are the most widely used)